# Get rid of unassigned shard

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I've an ELK stack with two ElasticSearch nodes running and the cluster state turned red due to some unassigned shards which I can't get rid of. Looking up the unassigned shard, resp. the incomplete index with:

```
# curl -s elastic01.local:9200/_cat/shards | grep "logstash-2014.09.29"
```

Shows:

```
logstash-2014.09.29 4 p STARTED       745489  481.3mb 10.165.98.107 Crimson and the Raven
logstash-2014.09.29 4 r STARTED       745489  481.3mb 10.165.98.106 Glenn Talbot
logstash-2014.09.29 0 p STARTED       781110  502.3mb 10.165.98.107 Crimson and the Raven
logstash-2014.09.29 0 r STARTED       781110  502.3mb 10.165.98.106 Glenn Talbot
logstash-2014.09.29 3 p INITIALIZING                  10.165.98.107 Crimson and the Raven
logstash-2014.09.29 3 r UNASSIGNED
logstash-2014.09.29 1 p STARTED       762991  490.1mb 10.165.98.107 Crimson and the Raven
logstash-2014.09.29 1 r STARTED       762991  490.1mb 10.165.98.106 Glenn Talbot
logstash-2014.09.29 2 p STARTED       761811  491.3mb 10.165.98.107 Crimson and the Raven
logstash-2014.09.29 2 r STARTED       761811  491.3mb 10.165.98.106 Glenn Talbot
```

My attempt to assign the shard to the other node fails:

```
curl XPOST -s 'http://elastic01.local:9200/_cluster/reroute?pretty=true' -d '{
    "commands" : [ {
            "allocate" : {
              "index" : "logstash-2014.09.29",
              "shard" : 3 ,
              "node" : "Glenn Talbot",
              "allow_primary" : 1
            } 
        }
    ]
}'
```

With:

```
NO(primary shard is not yet active)]
```

I can't really seem to find an API to push the shard states any further. How could I proceed here?

Just for a complete picture, that what the system health looks like:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "logstash_es",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 114,
  "active_shards" : 228,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 1,
  "unassigned_shards" : 1
}
```

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Deleting the shards and loosing the data was the only way to solve it, back then

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this situation with ElasticSearch 1.5 just the other day. After initially getting the same error, I simply **repeated** the `/_cluster/reroute` request the next day for lack of other ideas, and it worked, and it put the cluster back into a green state immediately.